# Returning a value from a mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I created an unique ID for each title submitted to my database. Now i need to return the data through my res.json and i cant seem to figure it out.

ive tried the db.collection.findOne command however i havent created a document to use this function. I just want to return the id that i created through my res.json. Thank You for any input :)

```
  'use strict';
   var express     = require('express');
   var app    = express();
   var expect = require('chai').expect;
   var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
   var mongo    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

   module.exports = function (app,db ) {
    app.route('/api/books')

   .post(function (req, res){


   db.collection('project').insertOne({
    "title": req.body.title,
    "_id": Math.floor(Math.random()* 100)
    })
    res.json({
      "status":"success",
     "_id": db.collection('project').findOne('test'),
      "title": req.body.title,

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to connect to mongodb database :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

 MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb", function (err, db) {

      var doc = { "title": req.body.title, "_id": Math.floor(Math.random()* 100) };

      db.collection('project').insertOne(doc, function (err, document) {
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
     } else {
        res.json({"status":"success","_id": document_id,"title":req.body.title})

        db.close();
     }
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to the function `insertOne` that contains the result of the inserted document

```
db.collection('project').insertOne(doc, function (err, document) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
       res.json({
         "status":"success",
         "_id": document_id,
         "title": req.body.title,
       })
    }
});
```